# xpages how to detect IOS screen rotation

Tags: ios, xpages

I know how to tell what orientation an IOS device is in on page load, but how to I detect when the screen is rotated during a page view? Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html There is a section named: Handling Orientation Events.

Most probably you will need to handle it with custom JS.